# How to make mod_ssl accept self signed certificates

Tags: apache, ssl, curl, ssl-certificate

I am using self signed certificates with Apache mod_ssl module but I am getting

```
> curl_easy_perform() failed on: https://localhost/auth/example (SSL
> certificate problem: self signed certificate)
```

Is their a way to make ssl not fail? I know that curl has the option --insecure or -k so is there something similar I can add to http-ssl.conf?

Answer (score 0):

`mod_ssl` will present whatever certificate it is configured to present.  It is a client decision whether to accept the presented certificate or not; there is nothing you can configure in `mod_ssl`, other than the certificate itself, that will influence client verification.

If you want Curl to accept the server certificate, you can either:

- Use `--insecure`/`-k` (as you are already aware)
- Obtain a certificate signed by a public, trusted *certificate authority* (CA)
- Use a *self-signed* CA to sign the server certificate, and tell Curl to verify the server certificate using that CA via the `--cacert <CA certificate>` option.